# Tablayout with recyclerview not swipeable on items

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-tablayout, motionevent

I'm using a tablayout with 3 fragments, each fragment has its own recyclerview.  When trying to swipe from a fragment on a item the tablayout doesn't change tabs. I probably have to override a certain motionevent, but I don't know how.

I hope someone has the answer to this!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that when you are using a RelativeLayout in the layout that you are inflating the swiping part doesn't work. After changing this to a LinearLayout it solved the problem!